# Child of anchor can't have text decoration removed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have a global javascript function which `.appends()` a tooltip element to any element with the `data-tooltip` attribute.

This is all cool until I try to give an `a`nchor the `data-tooltip` attribute, which seems to break the css because I cannot seem to remove the `text-decoration` rule on the tooltip.

*How do I remove `text-decoration` on the child of an anchor?*

The underline is clearly being inherited from the parent anchor, as it has the default anchor colour underline, but the `color` of the tooltip text is orange.

See http://img.ly/35kc for a clearer idea of what I am talking about.

**Update**

Here is my css for the tooltip, as requested

```
/*TOOLTIPS*/

.tooltip_placeholder {
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline;
    z-index: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip_boundary {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip_border {
    z-index: 100;
    background: url(/sales/global/images/tooltip_arrow.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px; /*left offset*/
    background-position: 16px 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tooltip {
    padding: 8px;
    color: #A97D35;
    background: #FBF98E;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
    border: 6px solid #F9E98E;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: none;
    z-index: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is how a tooltip is put in:

```
$(element).append('<div class="tooltip_placeholder"><div class="tooltip_boundary"><div class="tooltip_border" style="display: none;"><div class="tooltip">'+$(element).attr('data-tooltip')+'</div></div></div></div>')
```

**Update 2**

@Guffa has kindly fiddled this http://jsfiddle.net/TxRmk/
The issue appears to be browser specific, as I can get it to work in FF, not Safari or Chrome. Haven't checked IE, but it probably does something completely different

Comment: Can you post your CSS?  Shooting in the dark otherwise...

Comment: `a.iHasAToolTip .toolTipElement { text-decoration: none }`?

Comment: Post your HTML/CSS. It sounds like an issue of CSS specificity. A selector like the one in my previous comment may be good enough.

Comment: a jsFiddle example would be wonderful.

Comment: @Jeff See http://jsfiddle.net/TxRmk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CHSmV/

I couldnt get it to work without modifying your HTML. If you are able to do that, see my fiddle. I added an extra span around the non-tooltip text and added classes to both spans. Then I targeted the relevant spans with the proper `text-decoration`.

This worked in FF 3.6, IE 7+8, Safari 5 and Chrome 9.

Answer (score 0):

Did not modifying the tooltip class to remove underline work?
Add this to the class definition of tooltip.

```
text-decoration: none;
```

If this did not work, try using this:

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-tooltip]').children().css('text-decoration','none');
});
```

**UPDATE**

I think this behavior may be caused by browsers.
Why not making this work-around?

```
a:hover {text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Yup, thats the first thing I tried. Tried in all the tooltip elements too. (Tooltip is made up of 4 nested `div`s)

Comment: if you supply with div structure of tooltip, and css classes, it would be cleaner.

Comment: @Zak Henry do you have an `!important` declaration of `text-decoration` that could override this somewhere in your css?

Comment: @Damp nope. Good thought though

Comment: @Ottomanlast - Your last suggestion would work, except that I have a 5 second delay before the tooltip disappears. This would make the `text-decoration` come back after you 'un-hovered' the link

Answer (score 0):

WHen I try that, the `text-decoration` is not inherited:

http://jsfiddle.net/TxRmk/

CSS:

```
a { position: relative; }
a span { display: none; position: absolute; left: 10px; top 20px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; background: #ccc; color: #fff; }
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('span', this).css({ display: 'block' })
}, function(){
    $('span', this).css({ display: 'none' });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Info<span>Information</span></a>
```

Comment: Hm it is for me (Safafi 5.0.3). I'll test other browsers

Comment: @Guffa Its happy in firefox. Not so in Safari or Chrome

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/TxRmk/1/) in IE/Safari/Chrome. The `text-decoration` from the `a` tag can't be vanquished :o

Comment: @thirtydot See http://jsfiddle.net/TxRmk/5/ Your example worked because it was a span. `Div`s don't work

Comment: @Zak Henry: My example *didn't* work. That was the point I was trying to make. But, I didn't test it in Safari. I did test it in Chrome, and the underline on the span was still there so I didn't check it in Safari, thinking that because they're both WebKit, they would behave the same. A silly assumption from me.

Comment: @thirtydot ah yes I made the exact same assumption

Comment: @Zak Henry: You can't have a `div` element inside an `a` element, a block element can't be inside an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have one solution to my own question - Don't use `<div>` elements inside an anchor tag. I tried using `<span>` instead and it works correctly now

Comment: Scratch that. It works in Firefox, Safari. But not Chrome. :(